# Responsive SVG Path with SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, responsive-design

Is it possible to have a responsive `path` using **[SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/)**?

I have built the following  **[experiment on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/vdEbg)**, any i want my `path` to be responsive.

I'm building my path using the following code on **line 9** of my pen:

```
var myPathC = snapC.path("M62.9 14.9c-25-7.74-56.6 4.8-60...
```

However it is this path that i wish to be responsive or re-drawn when the browser window is resized. Anyone know if this is possible and/or have any ideas on how to approach it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give the container a viewBox attribute e.g.

```
<svg id="svgC" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 400"></svg>
```

and it will resize with the window.

Comment: should i be looking at this: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.getBBox ? I'm not really a JS wiz so struggling to make too much sense of the Snap Documentation. Thanks for the response also!

Comment: you could use getBBox to apply a transform to the path. It would lead to a more complicated solution though.

Comment: lovely, i've updated the CodePen example in the original question and i've got it working. viewBox is a little confusing but i've managed to accomplish what i need. I'll play with viewBox a bit more to better understand it i think!

Comment: This one helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've created a working svg that is responsive following the viewport suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        .shapeDemo {
            min-height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        svg .purpleCircle {
            fill: darkmagenta;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width:5;
        }

        svg .greenRectangle {
            fill: green;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 5;
        }

        svg .redRectangle {
            fill: red;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Responsive SVG sandbox</p>
    <svg class="shapeDemo" viewBox="0 0 600 400"> 
        <circle cx="75%" cy="10%" r="2.5%" class="purpleCircle"/>
        <circle cx="25%" cy="10%" r="1%" class="purpleCircle"/>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="22%" r="5%" class="purpleCircle"/>

        <rect x="20%" y="30%" width="10%" height="5%" class="redRectangle" />

        <rect x="45%" y="55%" width="10%" height="5%" rx="10" ry="10"
                    class="greenRectangle" />

        <ellipse cx="80%" cy="70%" rx="10%" ry="5%" />

        <polygon points="100,0 50,50 150,50"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```